# Excel Pivot Table - Uneven group interval

Tags: excel, grouping, pivot-table

I have around about 12,000 individual accounts with balances ranging from .01 to over 5mm. I want to group them in a column header so that I know the number of accounts that fall into each range as well as the summed up value of those accounts. I know how to create my pivot table to do this except for the grouping. I can only get one group to work (0-100,000 and >100,000). What I need is:

0-100,000; 100,000-1,000,000; 1,000,000-5,000,000; 5,000,000+

Can this be done? Manually grouping them isn't very viable given that I have 12,000 different account balances....and I wouldn't really want to do that manually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a calculated column to the source of the data with a formula to return the categories you want?  A nested "If" statement should handle it with ease. Something along the line of:

```
=IF(AND(BALANCE>0,BALANCE<100000),"0-100,0000",IF(AND(BALANCE>=100000,BALANCE<1000000),"100,000-1,000,000"))
```

Just add in the rest of the IF(AND(X,Y),"Display text") to generate your categories.

Comment: Yes, this is what I eventually did as I don't think there is a way to do it through the Pivot Table Grouping option. The other thing I attempted was to switch the column headings to rows and try manual grouping that way.....it was a pain.

Comment: Glad I could help.  Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could skip the Pivot table entirely and use `COUNTIFS`

```
=COUNTIFS(A$1:A$10,">"&0,A$1:A$8,"<="&100000)
=COUNTIFS(A$1:A$10,">"&100000,A$1:A$10,"<="&500000)
```

And so on

For the last category you can use a `COUNTIF`

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A$10,">"&5000000)
```

(My formulas assume the data is in Range `A1:A10`)